# variable using array 2D

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am writing a program on Visual Studio 2010,  and declaring  a variable as follows :

```
int image[512][512];
```

and the program run well. But when I modify the program as follows:

```
int image1[512][512];
int image2[512][512];
```

it is ok when compiling, but error when execution. The program stopped. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Are you declaring these as non-`static` local variables? If so, you may be overflowing the (not too big) stack.